# objective-c iphone sdk dragging image inside a box

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, joystick

I was thinking of make a slider/joystick but not in a circle but in a line. So I made the image drag able only over the X axis and when it gets to the point where the slider stops i did this :

```
if(slider.center.x <= 60) {
  slider.center = CGPointMake(60, slider.center.y);
}
```

so it wouldn't get bigger than 60 but i was thinking isn't there a better way to do this? like make a box and setting up something to not drag it outside that box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this method is very good. As far as I know there is no wan to stop dragging in other ways than this.
However there is a control called `UISlider`. This control does the functionality you would like to have.

Comment: yeah i know but its ugly :p but if this s a nice way then its ok :)

Comment: Yes, this is a nice way, since there is no better method. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use touchesBegan, touchesMoved, and touchesEnded, then add an image behind and detect when touch is less than half image's width (Left) or when it's greater than half (Right)